# Winsock structure to store path for IPC

Tags: sockets, ipc, winsock

In unix the sockaddr_un structure exists to hold a path. Is there some windows equivalent. I've been looking all over the place and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use UNIX domain sockets on Windows, [Windows Services for Unix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496506.aspx) might help.

If you're looking for a similar IPC mechanism native to Windows, you probably want [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590.aspx).